# Current row placeholders in an Excel array formula

Tags: excel

I have an Excel worksheet where there are event dates on the x axis and different categories of occurrences on the y axis. The occurrence values are numeric, `]0, 1]`. Not every category has a value in every event.

I want to get the sum of the 5 latest (= rightmost) occurrence values, i.e. sum the values of the 5 leftmost cells that contain a number on every row. I have an array formula that works in principle (example for row 4):

```
=SUM(IF(COLUMN(B4:AP4)>=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER(B4:AP4);COLUMN(B4:AP4));5);B4:AP4))
```

The data ranges from column G to column AP, and the columns B–F contain zeroes in order for the function to work when there are less than 5 occurrences.

The problem is that there are currently 92 classes of occurrences (92 rows), and I would like to have a placeholder for the current row in the syntax. I tried this,

```
=SUM(IF(COLUMN((INDIRECT("B"&ROW()&":AP"&ROW())))
>=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER((INDIRECT("B"&ROW()&":AP"&ROW())));
COLUMN((INDIRECT("B"&ROW()&":AP"&ROW()))));5);(INDIRECT("B"&ROW()&":AP"&ROW()))))
```

but it doesn’t work. Is there a way to make an easily copypasteable piece of code to do this?

Comment: without trying to replicate on a computer, it looks like your limitation with copy and paste comes from hard coding column B, like in this snipetp of your code `INDIRECT("B"&ROW()` was there a reason for this?  Why not use the column () function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were nearly there. Wrap each `ROW()` call inside a `SUM`. You don't want an array for the row reference but the row number.

```
=SUM(IF(COLUMN((INDIRECT("B"&SUM(ROW())&":AP"&SUM(ROW()))))
>=LARGE(IF(ISNUMBER((INDIRECT("B"&SUM(ROW())&":AP"&SUM(ROW())))),
COLUMN((INDIRECT("B"&SUM(ROW())&":AP"&SUM(ROW()))))),5),(INDIRECT("B"&SUM(ROW())&":AP"&SUM(ROW())))))
```